# Should I use prepared statements in while loops?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am revisiting my code to refactor it and debating if whether or not I should use mysql prepared statements. The only goal I am trying to accomplish, is to  simply display menu items for a restaurant food ordering website. That's all. It will select menu items from a database and display them using a while loop.

Upon reading the documentation in php's website. They said that prepared statements are more efficient when statements are repeated.

But all I am doing is querying the table once  and preforming a while loop when a user visits my page.

So is it really necessary to use prepared statements other than the fact that is prevents SQL injection?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing in that one query; i.e. does it use variables that are posted to the script from outside?

Answer (score 0):

Using prepared statements not only prevents SQL injection, it also ensures that your program's flow follows a pattern of object-oriented programming. This way you can continue developing your application in an OO way, thus allowing you to take advantage of various practises found in most modern ORMs.

The difference in performance is something I would choose to neglect in this particular case, given the other options, which aren't that many. Switching to a procedural and deprecated way of PHP `mysql-*` functions obviously isn't the answer, and if you're in a world of Python or Ruby, then you'll still find that the very foundation of almost every modern ORM relies on the concepts of object-oriented code flow.

Comment: I wasnt really referring to a procedural way of coding. I still use OOP mysqli queries. I just wanted to know if it is worth using prepared statements for while loops..